# xdotool not executing 'type' depending on how I start it from vim

Tags: ubuntu, vim, xdotool

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Find the Firefox window with a title containing 'Plan page'
firefox_window_id=$(xdotool search --name "Plan page")
echo "Firefox Id is" + $firefox_window_id
xdotool windowactivate "$firefox_window_id"
xdotool type "y"
```

It's purpose is to find a particular firefox window and send the key "y"

It works perfectly from the command line, but I'd like it as a Vim macro.

If I run it like this:

```
:! ~/git/delores/mcve.sh
```

it works perfectly.

But if I run it like this:

```
noremap ,ny :! /home/joe/git/delores/mcve.sh<cr>
```

Then xdotool grabs the focus of the window but doesn't send the 'y' and keeps the focus of the firefox window. I get the same (bad) behavior when I run it from i3.  EDIT - adding a delay to the script means that the keypress is sent, but it's very unclear why that makes a difference...

Why would the script act differently depending on how I call it in Vim, and what can I do about it?

My OS is Ubuntu. I am using Vim 8.2.

Comment: @phd  darn-it! Fixed now, thanks for letting me know...

Comment: "I get the same (bad) behavior when I run it from i3." would be a good hint that your problem is not really related to vim.

Comment: @romainl - I think it's related to vim in the sense that vim seems to have two different ways of calling external things and I'd like to understand the difference.  I certainly think it's a lot broader than just vim tho.

Comment: Does it show the same problem if the last key in the mapping isn't "y"?